# Contruct 3d array in numpy from existing 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

During preparing data for NumPy calculate. I am curious about way to construct:

```
myarray.shape => (2,18,18)
```

from:

```
d1.shape => (18,18)
d2.shape => (18,18)
```

I try to use NumPy command:

```
hstack([[d1],[d2]])
```

but it looks not work!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

hstack and vstack do no change the number of dimensions of the arrays: they merely put them "side by side".  Thus, combining 2-dimensional arrays creates a new 2-dimensional array (not a 3D one!).

You can do what Daniel suggested (directly use `numpy.array([d1, d2])`).

You can alternatively convert your arrays to 3D arrays before stacking them, by adding a new dimension to each array:

```
d3 = numpy.vstack([ d1[newaxis,...], d2[newaxis,...] ])  # shape = (2, 18, 18)
```

In fact, `d1[newaxis,...].shape == (1, 18, 18)`, and you can stack both 3D arrays directly and get the new 3D array (`d3`) that you wanted.

Comment: `np.vstack([a[np.newaxis,...],b[np.newaxis,...]])` worked like charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

Just doing `d3 = array([d1,d2])` seems to work for me:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> # ... create d1 and d2 ...
>>> d1.shape
(18,18)
>>> d2.shape
(18,18)
>>> d3 = array([d1, d2])
>>> d3.shape
(2, 18, 18)
```

Comment: I have one question similar. If I have already got the d3 with shape(2,18,18) and I want to add another 2-d array d4 (18x18) into d3 to make 3-d array(3,18,18). What should I do?

Comment: You simply `vstack(d3, d4[np.newaxis,...])`, as in my answer.

Comment: It must be vstack((d3, d4[np.newaxis,...])). Two '(( ))' are needed.

Answer (score 13):

```
arr3=np.dstack([arr1, arr2])
```

arr1, arr2 are 2d array `shape (256,256)`, arr3: `shape(256,256,2)`

Comment: Up for this, because it works for joining RGB channels on images too, as the final shape must be `(height,width,3)`.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of versatility is provided by the `np.stack()` function. You can use it like this:

```
>>> d3 = np.stack([d1, d2])
>>> d3.shape
(2, 18, 18)
```

However you can also specify the axis along which the arrays get joined. So if you wanted to join channels of a RGB image, you would use:

```
>>> rgb = np.stack([r, g, b], axis=-1) # r, g and b each have shape (18, 18)
>>> rgb.shape
(18, 18, 3)
```