# combine 2-d array to existing 3-d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
>>>d1.shape
>>>(18,18)
>>>d2.shape
>>>(18,18)
>>>d3 = array([d1, d2])
>>>d3.shape
>>>(2, 18, 18)
```

If I have already got the d3 with shape(2,18,18) and I want to add another 2-d array d4 (18x18) into d3 to make 3-d array(3,18,18).
 What should I do?

====2015-12-31=====

#### Summary

From the answer below, I collect some useful code here

> 1. `d3 = np.concatenate([d3, d4.reshape(1, d3.shape[0],d4.shape[1])])`
> 2. `d3 = np.vstack([d3, d4[None, ...]])`

#### PS

After my test for construct 3-d array(681x50x60) by reading 681 .csv file,
the second method was more efficient(19 s) than the first method(28 s) on the same laptop.

Comment: Reshape your new array as (1, 18, 18) and use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: You might also consider stacking things along the third axis instead of the first, if you have the option.  It works more naturally with numpy's broadcasting, and you'll be able to use `np.dstack` to do exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be useful, but I imagine there is a more efficient way to achieve the same result...

```
import numpy as np
d1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
d2 = np.array([[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]])
d3 = np.array([d1, d2])

dnew = np.array([[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]])
d3 = np.array([dnew] + [d3[a, ...] for a in range(d3.shape[0])])

# Add to the end of the array
dlast = np.array([[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]])
d3 = np.array([d3[a, ...] for a in range(d3.shape[0])] + [dlast])
```

**Edit: There is a better way**

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728092/2372604) the stack command is used to literally stack the arrays together.  As an example consider:

```
import numpy as np
d1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
d2 = np.array([[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]])
d3 = np.array([d1, d2])

dnew = np.array([[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]])
d3 = np.vstack([d3, dnew[None, ...]])
```

There is an important difference between using `np.vstack` and just creating a new array using `np.array`.  The latter (tested on numpy version 1.8.2) produces an array of two objects while stack produces a single numpy array.

Comment: `np.vstack` is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Same as you did with `d3` only you have to reshape `d4` into a 3-d array:

`d3 = array([d3, d4.reshape(1, 18, 18)])`

or

`d3 = concatenate([d3, d4.reshape(1, 18, 18)])`

Comment: On a side note, `d4.reshape(1, 18, 18)` can also be done as `d4[None, ...]` or `d4[np.newaxis, ...]`.  The `Ellipsis` effectively fills in the other dimensions without needing to know their exact size.  Slicing with `None` and/or `newaxis` (they're the same object) adds a new singleton dimension.

Comment: Is the shape of `d3` correct after this or does `d3` become a array of two numpy arrays?

Comment: @ilent2 the shape of d3 after this is (3, 18, 18)

Comment: @ZachiShtain Which version of numpy are you using and can you post the code to reproduce your result?  Perhaps I'm typing the wrong thing...

Comment: @ilent2 i am using numpy 1.9.0